# Change icon and cursor theme in dwm

Tags: theme, icons, cursor, dwm

I just installed my own dwm 
I patched in [systray](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray) and I would like to change the icon theme it uses away from adiwaita to something else (Arch ,Faba, Moka or breeze).

I tried changing to gnome, and then changing the theme, this worked for the cursor (I couldn't change it from within dwm) but not the systray icons.

Is there a way for me to change the systray icon-theme (within or outside dwm)??

Is there a way for me to change the cursor theme (without leaving dwm)?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Were you ever able to get this done?

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 No sadly not (Well, I guess I just didn't spend enough time on it) ;-(

Answer (score 3):

I'm also the newcomer to `dwm` who is also confused about the configuration of theme and icon until I find this [config gtk theme](https://github.com/antoniosarosi/dotfiles/blob/master/README.md#gtk-theming). Hope to help you!

Answer (score 1):

**The cursor is handled by the X server, not by `dwm`**. Therefore, the easiest way is to use `xrdb` and/or the `~/.Xresources` file, or `lxappearance` if you prefer GUIs.

For more information, visit the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes).